# How do pointers stay valid when objects move in memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Imagine in C I allocate two structs on the heap. One of the structs has a field which holds a pointer to the other struct.

As far as I know, data in the heap may move, thus addresses of things change. For example, defragmentation on the heap may occur, moving the second struct to a different place in the heap.

This help understanding what I'm talking about 
https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Memory_Management/Memory_Compacting

The point to this struct would now be wrong (i.e. holding the wrong memory address).

I don't mean this question as specific to C, but more general: at any time, the platform may decide to move things around. How do pointers stay valid?

Comment: You mean fragmentation right? Please post a reference to *at any time, the platform may decide to move things around*? What do you mean with that?

Comment: @iharob I mean defragmentation: objects are moved to close a gap, and their addresses change.

Comment: Can you please give me a link where they explain how and when a given platform does that?

Comment: Concerning C : the pointers don't stay valid, but it actually doesn't matter, because the address of allocated objects never change.

Comment: "As far as I know, data in the heap may move" -> not in C, but in other languages that does happen.  The big exception is `realloc()`, but (1) you call that explicitly, and (2) it returns the new pointer for obvious reasons.

Comment: For platforms like .Net (not C), *they don't*, which is why you need to "pin" a pointer to keep it from being moved.

Comment: 'As far as I know, data in the heap may move' - I hope not!

Comment: Data in the heap of C (C++) does not move (at least from the point of view of the application process). Are you referring to moving objects like in a (generational) garbage collector? I.e. like Java does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key concept here is [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Your pointers do not point to a physical address, but rather to a virtual one in the virtual *address space* of your process. What you said is correct, data may get moved around, even swapped out to disk and then mapped again into the physical memory onto another frame, but the virtual address that your pointer points to stays always the same.

Comment: I highly doubt that this is what the OP is asking for. Your answer is more about the operating system level while the OP seems to be more concerned about the application level (for example, "memory moving around" as in a generational garbage collector). Though the virtual address translation (usually done by a memory management unit on chip with the CPU) is similar to what one could implement to solve this on application level.

Answer (score 5):

The C standard does not permit the implementation to (spontaneously) move things around in such a way that would invalidate an existing pointer. It's possible that an implementation could exist that does "defragment" the heap, but I don't know of any implementations that do.

I said "spontaneously" because `realloc()` calls in your code may actually cause the object to move; that's why `realloc` returns a pointer. If the pointer returned by `realloc` is different from the original pointer, the original pointer (and any pointers that aliased it) are invalid. But this is something you have to keep track of in your own code.

Managed languages (Java, C#, Python, whatever) may (or may not) deal with heap fragmentation by adding an additional level of indirection and/or keeping track of pointers into the heap. That way the language runtime can update all the pointers to object X when X moves to a different place. That would be taken care of by the garbage collection system.

It would be *somewhat unusual* for a C implementation to provide a garbage collector, and probably can't be done in a standards conformant way due to all the things you can (safely) do with pointers. So the premise of your question, that the heap may be spontaneously defragmented by the implementation, is not valid.

Comment: Good answer! But: You can write a garbage collector in C as well as for C: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/12/08/babys-first-garbage-collector/ and of course http://www.hboehm.info/gc/ .

Comment: @DanielJour: Normally (if you're doing anything like that) you add extra info to the raw pointer and call it a "reference" or something because it's no longer just a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

When you see a pointer in C, you observe something that looks like a memory address but, in practice, there will be one if not two levels of abstraction between this and the physical memory address.

Not only does this help make operating systems more secure but it allows it to perform any fragmentation tasks (whatever they are) without changing what is observed by your C program.